# How can I locate the source of a washing machine leak?

Tags: leak, washing-machine

I have an older washing maching, a Hotpoint 6 cycle heavy duty high capacity (I see a label with WLW3400, which I assume is the model number).

It is leaking and I am trying to discern the source. I have verified that is neither the input hoses nor the discharge hose (I was initially guessing the latter).

Other than a pinhole in the drum (which seems unlikely; it doesn't seem to leak until it well into the wash; I would think a drum hole would cause leakage very quickly... unless it's very high, I guess), what other sources of leaks could there be?

I did find this thread: [Why does my washing machine leak only during the spin cycle?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8474/why-does-my-washing-machine-leak-only-during-the-spin-cycle) which mentions a belt, although it doesn't explain how water can leak from a belt being loose (I can certainly imagine other problems, and the machine does have some vibration issues at times).

Comment: Have you tried removing the panels and just watching it run?

Comment: There's several hose connections inside the machine, as well as other components that can leak. There's a good chance that by removing the panels, you will see evidence of leakage without even the need to run the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I worked briefly for Sears fixing washers. A trick we used to find leaks was to put A sheet of newspaper under the machine until the leak starts. Then pull out the sheet. It will show you roughly where the leak is or where the water gets out, not always the same thing!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 0):

Does the leak occur when the machine is on spin?
The pinhole could be the problem if centrifugal force is pushing water into the hole.

Comment: Hello again. This is a very old question; the OP is unlikely to respond to your query.